# Extracting multiple json lines from text file and print each line

Tags: php, json

I am trying to make my applications log file readable for the system, and i am currently logging it to a file named `AccessLog.txt`

What i want to do is to allow php to read the whole file and output set variables if they match any criteria when searching in the log.

my current log file looks like this:

```
{"Action":"Edited file","User":null,"Timestamp":"25-09-2015 09:55","URL":"\/run.php?type=EDIT"}
{"Action":"Edited file","User":null,"Timestamp":"25-09-2015 09:55","URL":"\/run.php?type=EDIT"}
{"Action":"Edited file","User":null,"Timestamp":"25-09-2015 09:55","URL":"\/run.php?type=EDIT"}
{"Action":"Edited file","User":null,"Timestamp":"25-09-2015 09:55","URL":"\/run.php?type=EDIT"}
```

Now, i want to be able to export everything in here for my search to work, my problem is that i tried to read the file and then use `explode("\n",$File);` to split every line into an array.

I expected to get this in a `json_decode();` format.

I have tried this:

```
function readFile($File){
$Path = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$File");


$Document = fread($Path);
$Data = explode("\n", $Document);

foreach ($Data as $Line){
    $Output = json_decode($Line);

    $print .= "Action: ".$Output->Action."<br/>";
    $print .= "User: ".$Output->User."<br/>";
    $print .= "When: ".$Output->Timestamp."<br/>";
    $print .= "Location: ".$Output->URL."<hr>";
}

fclose($Path);
return $print;

}

echo readFile("AccessLog.txt");
```

Any tips on what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)? It expects two arguments and it returns `FALSE` because you provide only one. More, it triggers a warning that says where the problem is: "fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given". Anyway, `fread()` doesn't help you very much; try [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php). It allows you to read the file line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you shouldnt use readFile, that function already exists within php. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

I've rewritten it for you,

```
function readJsonFile($File){

  // open the file to with the R flag,
    $Path = fopen($File,"r");

    // if file found,
    if ($Path) {
        $print = '';

            // for each line
            while (($line = fgets($Path)) !== false) {
                $Output = json_decode($line);
                $print .= "Action: ".$Output->Action."<br/>";
                $print .= "User: ".$Output->User."<br/>";
                $print .= "When: ".$Output->Timestamp."<br/>";
                $print .= "Location: ".$Output->URL."<hr>";
            }

            // close file
        fclose($Path);
    } else {
        $print = 'Error, File not found';
    }
    return $print;
}

echo readJsonFile("AccessLog.txt");
```

Comment: Also, your Json file is poorly written, you should be having a comma after the closing } on each line, EG

{},
{},

Comment: Thanks! will remember that, the file is written from an array: `$Log = array(value, value);` then `$Save = json_encode($Log); ` so i dont know how i would make it better